# Get XML node with specified type in JS

Tags: javascript, xml

Is there any built in function in JavaScript to get only element nodes, or do I have to add another loop which counts the actual number of those if I need it before, like:

```
l = 0;
for(i = 0; i < x.childNodes.length; i++){
    if(x.childNodes[i].nodeType = 1) l++;       
}

for(i = 0; i < x.childNodes.length; i++){
    if(x.childNodes[i].nodeType != 1) continue;
    new Something(l);   
}
```

Comment: Try `.children` instead of `.childNodes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Node.[children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children)** is a read-only property that returns a live
>   HTMLCollection of the child elements of Node.

**Syntax**

```
var elList = elementNodeReference.children;
```

> elList is a HTMLCollection, which is an ordered collection of DOM
>   elements that are children of elementNodeReference. If there are no
>   element children, then elList contains no elements and has a length of
>   0.

Comment: This is what i wanted but should I change the question title because I accepted the question but it not match the title exactly?